# Python Tkinter changing Button Text with row and column

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following problem, i have a 7 x 7 grid filled with butoons and the following problem is:
I want to replace the text later on the buttons, but with the help of the rows and columns, how is that possible?

```
import tkinter as tk

def click(row, col):
    print(row, col)
    label.configure(text="you clicked row %s column %s" % (row, col))

test_text = "TEST"

root = tk.Tk()
for row in range(1,8):
    for col in range(1,8):
        button = tk.Button(root, text=test_text, 
                           command=lambda row=row, col=col: click(row, col))
        button.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="nsew")
label = tk.Label(root, text="")
label.grid(row=8, column=1, columnspan=8, sticky="new")

root.grid_rowconfigure(10, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(10, weight=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There could be multiple ways of accomplishing this.

Comment: can you give me a hint or a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the buttons to change their text. Here is an example.

```
import tkinter as tk

def click(row, col):
    print(row, col)
    label.configure(text="you clicked row %s column %s" % (row, col))
    buttons[row-1][col-1].config(text='Foo')

test_text = "TEST"

root = tk.Tk()

buttons = []
for row in range(1,8):
    button_row = []
    for col in range(1,8):
        button = tk.Button(root, text=test_text, 
                           command=lambda row=row, col=col: click(row, col))
        button.grid(row=row, column=col, sticky="nsew")
        button_row.append(button)
    buttons.append(button_row)

label = tk.Label(root, text="")
label.grid(row=8, column=1, columnspan=8, sticky="new")

root.grid_rowconfigure(10, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(10, weight=1)


root.mainloop()
```

I had to use `row-1` and `col-1` in the handler to correct the index.

Comment: i have changed something on the array yet i didn´t need the -1

Comment: The decrement is only needed in the `click` handler because the row and column parameters are off-by-one from the `buttons` array indexes. If you use indexes directly, you don't need the decrement.